# MySQL syntax errors using UniServerZ

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have written some SQL and have run it to find errors in practically all of the tables. This is the error I have gotten for the tables:

```
 Error creating table 'Region': You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'desc varchar(25) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(regID))' at line 1
```

My code:

```
mysql_select_db($dbName, $dbConnection);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$dbTableRegion." (regID int(4) auto_increment NOT NULL, desc varchar(25) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(regID))";
if(mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection))
{
    echo("Table '".$dbTableRegion."' created<br />");
}
else
{
    echo("Error creating table '".$dbTableRegion."': ".mysql_error()."<br />");
}
```

Comment: you can use ` to enclose desc. it is system word in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Please rename `desc` on this line:

```
desc varchar(25) NOT NULL
```

To something else because it is a [reserverd word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL:

```
some_stuff varchar(25) NOT NULL
```

Comment: it can be enclosed by `